# Commerce Recurring Framework - Get active subscriptions?

Tags: commerce

For the Drupal Commerce Recurring Framework module I have a quesiton

Is there a way to get a user's active subscriptions programatically?

Bonus: Is there a way to delete a user's active subscriptions programmatically?

Thanks if anyone answers!

Comment: Drupal 6, 7 or 8?

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7:
Yes, you can find the data at the `{commerce_recurring}` database. With each recurring entity the user id has saved (uid column).

Here's an example how to get all subscription (recurring entities) from a user.

```
$uid = 1; // the user id
$result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {commerce_recurring} WHERE uid = :uid', array(':uid' => $user_from_order->uid));
```

Now you can loop over the subscriptions / recurring entities.